# Which version of Visual Studio Meets our Requirements?

Tags: visual-studio

We're a small team of developers working in remote offices, currently developing in VS2012 (and in VS2008 for some really old stuff). We're interested in moving to VS2015 in order to deploy MVC5 for new web projects. I'm getting really confused; however, by the options we have available and the Microsoft site simply refers me to a reseller who is only interested in giving me a price, not explaining what we need to purchase.

1. We primarily develop web applications, previously all web forms apps
2. We occasionally build console or other compile apps for execution on remote servers
3. We currently use Source Gear's Vault product for source code management.
4. We currently use Telerik's testing suite for automated testing which I find clunky and it's load testing capabilities are not good (specifically reporting). We'll need to continue testing so a VS version with good support for testing is a must.

It sounds like I'm leaning towards Professional, but don't know what we gain by moving to Code. For one thing we can't afford $6k per seat for code, and even the $1k for pro is big.

Comment: I suggest changing the title to "Which version of Visual Studio matches our requirements?" or similar, to make clear why the question belongs here (which I *think* it does).

Comment: How small is "small"? Maybe Visual Studio Community would fit your situation and it's free.

Comment: Alejandro, we're 3 right now. I've been very wary of Azure after having tons of problems connecting to their DB environment from our managed 2012 servers, so the idea of pushing our valuable IP up to the Microsoft cloud bugs me.  That's why I've been initially hesitant to embrace the community edition.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Your question is pretty borderline: for one, you've already decided what product you want, for the other this comes close to a product comparison request (see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/69/185)). It would be much better if you'd list your requirements and open your mind to other products as well – which might make it easier to find something really fitting and avoiding your price issue.